# Equivalence between definitions of family of generators.

Tags: category-theory

Yet another question about the *Tôhoku Paper* I know this might be quite elementary but anyway.

I've always used the definition of $( G_i )_{i \in I}$ is a family of generators of a category $\mathscr{C}$ iff  given $u,v : A \rightarrow B$ if  $\forall g \in Hom(G_i,A)$ we have $u \circ g = v \circ g \implies u=v$

However in the paper it says that $( G_i )_{i \in I}$ is a family of generators iff  given a subobject $A \rightarrowtail B$ there's a morphism $h: G_i \rightarrow B$ such that it doesn't factor through $A$.

Are these two notions always equivalent? If that's the case I'd like to know how to prove this. I feel like the second definition is somehow stronger but I have no idea.

Comment: They are not always equivalent. But they are equivalent in e.g. abelian categories.